# Best Way to set background color for a particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

Consider I have ten thousand divs, which have default background color as grey, but when I click on a particular div the background color should be changed to green.

Just for 5 elements I tried

```
<div id='1'>1</div>
<div id='2'>2</div>
<div id='3'>3</div>
<div id='4'>4</div>
<div id='5'>5</div>
```

JS:

```
$('div').each(function(i, j){
console.log(j);
    $(j).click(function(index, ele){
        $('div').css({'background-color': 'grey'});
$('div#'+index.currentTarget.id).css({'background-color': 'green'});

    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hng0599/)

This is working, but what if there is say like 10000 divs , performance will be an issue, and I want a better approach.

Comment: Your ids are wrong, ID attribute must always start with a letter.

Comment: @Ahmad: No, in HTML5 they don’t.

Comment: @CBroe yep, still the other way validates HTML5 and previous versions

Comment: @Ahmad: Whether or not it _validates_ as older versions doesn’t really matter – that’s why you _specify_ which HTML version you use via doctype declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code a lot:

```
var div = $('div'); // cache for performance

div.on('click', function() {
    div.css('backgroundColor', 'grey');
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'green'; // use pure JS instead of wrapping it again for performance
});
```

Comment: Hey, Can we do the same using event.bubbles, Because for ten thousand divs, it will be performance issue, to bind the click event for all those divs ?, If you are aware of the event.bubbles, can you please show me the demo for the same.

Comment: If i understand correctly:
`$(document).on('click', 'div', function() { /* ... */ });`

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to loop over all elements and set a seperate event-listener on them.

I would add a certain class to these div's to distinguish them from other divs on your page which you will probably have, something like `clickable` for example

```
<div class="clickable" id="1">1</div>
<div class="clickable" id="2">2</div>
<div class="clickable" id="3">3</div>
```

Now you can use a simple selector.

```
var clickableElements = $('.clickable');
clickableElements.on('click', function(){
     // in this scope, "this" will refer to the clicked element
     clickableElements.css({'background-color': 'grey'});
     $(this).css({'background-color': 'green'});
});
```

Storing the selector-call in a variable (`clickableElements`) is useful, because you don't have to select the elements alltogether again in the DOM

Another thing I would advice here is using classes for the actual styling, it is a lot more maintainable in my opinion and seperates your js-logic from the actual styling, as you can easily specify, modify and extend them in your CSS.

CSS:

```
.active-element{
    background: green;
}

.inactive-element{
    background: grey;
}
```

The click-handler would change to the following then:

```
clickableElements.on('click', function(){

     clickableElements.removeClass('active-element').addClass('inactive-element');
     $(this).removeClass('inactive-element').addClass('active-element');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using **Pure JavaScript** must be the **fastest** way to solve this.

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var size = div.length;

function changeColor(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#27f'; // or any color
}
for( var i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
    div[i].onclick = changeColor;
}
```

here the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrGeneral/nb6tpm39/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want:

```
$('div').click(function(){
    $('div').css({'background-color': 'grey'});
    $(this).css({'background-color': 'green'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

css

```
<style>
div{ background-color:#f5f5f5;}
.selected{ background-color:#f00;}
</style>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function(){
        $('div').on('click',function () {
             $('div').removeClass('selected');
             $(this).addClass('selected')
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Html

```
<div id='1'>1</div>
<div id='2'>2</div>
<div id='3'>3</div>
<div id='4'>4</div>
<div id='5'>5</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with something like this:

```
var currentTargetId = 0;

$('div').click(function(){
        $("#"+currentTargetId).css({'background-color': 'grey'});
        $(this).css({'background-color': 'green'});
       currentTargetId = $(this).attr("id");

});
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lparcerisa/5ts2k1g7/